# Dynamically Rename Shared OR object names

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

As per the naming convention we are following, we need to rename every object to its standard name.
One such convention is to replace space between with ‘_’

eg. Object name ->Object_name

**Is there any way to perform it dynamically using lines of code.?**

Comment: Variable/Object names can't have spaces to begin with. Can you show an example from your code?

Comment: sorry,the space is not at the beginning.I will be between the different parts of name like "PO Number".
"PO Number" needed to changed to "PO_Number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the OR to xml file and use the following line of code.
And use the xml generated to import OR back to QTP.
***This is specific to SAP GUI***

```
Function  ModifyORXML(inputFilepath,outputFilepath)
Set xmlDoc =  CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load(inputFilepath)
Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("qtpRep:Object")
num = xmlNodeList.length

For each x in xmlNodeList
    AttName=x.getattribute("Name")
    If x.getattribute("Class")="SAPGuiButton" Then
        tmp=Split(AttName," ",-1,1)
        AttName=tmp(0)
    End If
    AttName=Replace(AttName,Chr(34)," ")
    AttName=Replace(AttName,")"," ")
    AttName=Trim(AttName)           
    oldAttName=AttName
    AttName=Replace(AttName,":"," ")                
    AttName=Trim(AttName)
    AttName=Replace(AttName," ","_")    
    AttName=Replace(AttName," __","_",1,-1,1)   
    x.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name").Text = AttName
Next    
xmlDoc.Save outputFilepath  
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do , Export the repository to the XML . Then Using the XML dom Object you can navigate to each  Node.Each Node will have a Name Attribute .Then you can check there is a space if it is You can change the logical name of it .This will change the Object Repository Names .

But you need do similar king of change in your QTPscript to get reflected .